# How to save multiple values into one text file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to save multiple values from multiple text boxes into one text file. I'm able to save only the `firstName` but not the `Surname`. Any suggestion on how to save the both surname and the first name into one single textfile?

This is my controller:

```
    public class SampleController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Sample/
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Information information)
        {
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(information.FirstName);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            return File(stream, "text/plain", "your_file_name.txt");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a temporary variable to store both info using some kind of separator (a space?) then GetBytes from this temp

Comment: Consider also that the ASCII Encoding is not the best solution to use against people's names

Comment: can you please help me in term of code?

Comment: What is not clear in my first comment?

Comment: Just create a single string containing both data items. Something like `GetBytes(information.FirstName + " " + information.LastName)`, maybe? And I second the point about encoding. UTF-8 is preferable.

Comment: thnks guys its working

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Sample/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Information information)
    {
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(information.FirstName + ";" + information.SureName);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        return File(stream, "text/plain", "your_file_name.txt");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```